# EL expression is not resolved

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, apache-tomee

I just set up a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse running on TomEE and the advanced Hello World-Project just won't work:

xhtml-code like this

```
<h:outputText value="#{helloBean.hello()}"/> World!
```

will result in the page to be displayed without any errors like this:

```
World!
```

The bean has a `@Named`-Annotation is `SessionScoped` and the method returns a String "Hello".

Comment: *"The bean has a @Named-Annotation is SessionScoped and the method returns a String "Hello"."* Words are not sufficient as SSCCE. Starters can make so many mistakes/misconceptions based on simple terms. Please post *real* code. Please also tell if JSF/EL has actually run by looking at generated HTML output via rightclick, *View Source* in browser. It could also be very good the cause that JSF/EL hasn't got the chance to run at all.

Comment: I just exported the project and run it now successfully on my laptop. So I suppose it's not a simple matter of project code. It's either an Eclipse-thing or an Application Server-thing. I did several restarts and full publishes, clean projects, builds via Eclipse (even restarted the IDE) on my workstation, but it wouldn't work. What might I forget. Should I have went to TomEE deploy folder and delete there?

Comment: Still can't get it working on my workstation, although it's the same code. Probably I played too much with Project Facets? I can not even find a TomEE-folder where the project is deployed.
The EL was somehow processed as the was completely nothing in html-output. Now after playing with project facets the EL is just printed in output. The results feel inconsistent. :(

Comment: On my Workstation I exported and reimported the project, too. Now it works. I also noticed that, when I execute full publish now, the console states `INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ProjectName] is completed` which it didn't do before.

Comment: I'd blame the Eclipse plugin for TomEE or at least TomEE itself. Never really used it though, so can't tell from experience. I've used it only once to test a potential OmniFaces issue, but as far as I recall there were no surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h:outputText value="#{helloBean.hello}"/> World!
```